# Hibernate changing the inserted values?

Tags: sql, hibernate, insert

I have a persistent object like this

```
class Foo
{
   private String id;
   ......
   ......
   private List<Privileges> privileges;
   ......
}
```

Now the classes Foo and Privileges map to different tables.
I fill up the values of member variables of Foo like id and privileges and invoke

```
session.saveorupdate(fooObject);
```

I find that the data inserted into the privileges table is somehow changed? There is a member variable called id inside privileges that I confirmed to be equal to 10007 but hibernate magically just inserts 7 - a totally different value. What wrong is going on here?

Comment: is `id` in Priviliges annotated with `@Id` and/or `@GeneratedValue`?

Comment: @Rosty I think its something to do with the way I specify foreign key constraints. I am working on it,

Comment: if you annotated your primary key with `@GeneratedValue` then that is most likely the root of the problem, since Hibernate automatically generates a primary key by itself. if not then it's hard to figure out with the given information.